# Postgresql update 200 random records

Tags: postgresql, random, sql-order-by, sql-limit, distinct-on

I've got a query returning 200 random distinct foo from my Database. I want to update the notes field for those rows.

```
select distinct on (foo, random()) *
from test
order by random(), foo
limit 200
```

```
update test
notes = 'Flag'
order by random()
limit 200
```

My first thought was to use order and limit inside update, but those don't work there.
Another option I thought was to use the select inside the update.

But I'm not really sure, that's why I came here. Any ideas to get sql to update 200 distinct random rows would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `foo` is your primary key, you could do a CTE and a semi-join:

```
with cte as (
  select foo
  from test 
  order by random()
  limit 200
)
update test t
set notes = 'Flag'
where exists (
  select null
  from cte c
  where t.foo = c.foo
)
```

This would be pretty efficient for large datasets.

You can also try this, which is a little simpler to follow but is less scalable in terms of performance.  For 200 rows, it should be fine.

```
update test f1
set notes = 'Flag'
where foo in (select foo from test order by random() limit 200)
```

If foo is not the primary key, just use whatever is.  If you don't have a PK, you can use all columns, but there is no guarantee you would only update 200 if that happens.